# Double integral with transformation; possible error in limits

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm asked to show that the following integral is true with the transformation $u = x+y$ and $y=uv$:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} e^{y/(x+y)} dx dy = \frac{e-1}2 $$

I found the determinant of the jacobian of the transformation is $-u$, and the exponent is just $v$ so the integral becomes $$\iint_R |-u|e^v du dv = \frac {u^2}2 e^v|_R$$ $$=\frac{(x+y)^2}2e^{y/(x+y)}|_{x=0}^{1-x}\;|_{y=0}^1$$ And plugging it all in doesn't work (AFAICT). For one, the x's don't all cancel.

I've looked at it 100 times. It's definitely written dxdy not dydx even though there is definitely an x in the integral. Maybe this is a typo and why my calculation isn't working out? I tried reversing the order to dydx and it didn't work. I tried changing the limit of integration to $1-y$ and it didn't work out.

I'm not even sure how to figure out the domain of integration in the uv-plane. Flipping things around yields y=uv and x=u-uv. But if my domain is bounded by x=0 and y=0 and y=1 (ignoring the last limit for now), then I have uv=o=u and uv=1. !?!

Am I just making an algebra mistake plugging everything in? Is there a way to handle a variable in it's own integral that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the integral should be
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} e^{y/(x+y)}\,dy\,dx\ :$$
the innermost integral has an $x$ in the limits and therefore cannot have $x$ as the variable.  (People do sometimes write the $dx$ and $dy$ in any old order and expect the correct order to be "obvious from context", but IMHO this is confusing and a really bad idea.)

Your Jacobian is correct and gives the integral
$$\int_?^?\int_?^? ue^v\,dv\,du\ ,$$
where we still have to determine the limits of integration.

First you should sketch the region in $(x,y)$ coordinates.  It's a triangle with vertices $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  I'm not good at posting diagrams online so please draw this for yourself.

Now $x+y=\hbox{constant}$ is a line parallel to the oblique side of the triangle and so it should be clear from the picture that the values of $x+y$ in the region go from $0$ to $1$.  So we are up to
$$\int_0^1\int_?^? ue^v\,dv\,du\ .$$
Next, we have $v=y/u$, and we have to determine the values of $v$ **for a fixed value of** $u$ (note that, it's the vital point).  Now consider the part of the line $x+y=u$ lying inside the triangle.  It goes from $(u,0)$ to $(0,u)$ - please draw this on your diagram, looking at it is much easier than a verbal explanation - and so values of $y$ go from $0$ to $u$, so values of $v$ go from $0$ to $1$.  So the integral is
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 ue^v\,dv\,du\ ,$$
and the rest is easy.

Hope this helps!