# What should be the limits in this integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

> Using the transformation $x+y = u$, $y = uv$, show that
>
> $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x} e^{\frac{y}{x+y}} \, dydx = \frac{e-1}{2}.$$

In above question. I am stuck in finding limits after transformation.

My approach :
$u = x + y$,
$v = \frac{y} {x+y}$

I have calculated Jacobian of transformation which is $u$.

Please help me in finding limits of integration.

[image]

Comment: Hint: Draw a picture.

Comment: @SeanRoberson picture of what? Please tell

Comment: Draw a picture of the region of integration, i.e., the inequalities $0 \leq 1 - x \leq y$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$. This should be the first thing you do in any multiple integration problem.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I have uploaded the region plotted using desmos. I still cannot understand how to proceed further.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1270924/321264

Answer (score 3):

You have two conditions

$$0 < y < 1 \quad \text{and} \quad 0 < x+y < 1. \tag{*}$$

Now the second one directly translates to $0 < u < 1$. For $v$, notice that we also have $0 < y < 1$. So we always have $0 < v < 1$. Conversely, given any $(u, v) \in (0, 1)$ we can recover $x$ and $y$ by

$$ x = u(1-v), \quad y = uv $$

In this way, the transformation $(u, v) = (u(x, y), v(x, y)) = (x+y, \frac{y}{x+y})$ is a bijection between the triangular region $\text{(*)}$ to the unit square $(0,1)^2$:

$\hspace{2em}$[image]

(Left: region for $(x,y)$. Right: region for $(u,v)$.) Therefore

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x} e^{\frac{y}{x+y}} \, dydx
= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} u e^v \, dudv
= \frac{e-1}{2}. $$

Comment: How does y<1 implies v<1 ?

Comment: @user150700, Strictly speaking, it is the condition $0 < x, y$ that guarantees $v < 1$. This is because $0 < x, y$ implies $0 < y < x+y$. Now divide each side by $x+y$ (which we already know to be positive) to obtain $0 < v < 1$.

Comment: Can we accurately say that v<1 is the only condition maybe by some argument v comes out to be less than 0.5 ?

Comment: @user150700, That is a valid point. And that is why I provided an argument that you can recover points $(x, y)$ in the original domain from any points $(u, v)$ in the unit square. This way, you know that your change of variables exhausts all the points in the unit square in $uv$-plane.

Comment: y = 1- x  implies y is 1 when x is 0 and y is 0 when x is one. Then shouldn't the range of x + y be {1} only?

Comment: @user150700 Not sure what you are asking. The image of the line $y = 1-x$ under the map $(x, y)\mapsto x+y$ is $\{1\}$ only. This corresponds to the fact that the hypotenuse of the triangular domain of $(x, y)$ is mapped to the rightmost edge of the square domain of $(u, v)$, as you may read out from graphs above.

Comment: y = 1- x implies y is 1 when x is 0 and y is 0 when x is one. Then shouldn't the range of x + y be {1} only? If its true then u is 1 only not u in [0,1]?

Comment: @user150700 As I said, the range of $(x, y) \mapsto x+y$ restricted to the line $y = 1-x$ is a singleton $\{1\}$. But this has little to do with our transformation. Our transformation $(x,y)\mapsto(x+y,\frac{y}{x+y})$ is defined for all of the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$. Your line $y = 1-x$ represents only a minuscule fraction of the whole domain that you should look at.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.