# Double integration using Jacobians

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

I have to integrate this:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x} \exp\left(\frac{y}{x + y}\right)
\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
using the substitution $x + y = u$ and $y = uv$.

Now, under the given transformation boundary

$x=0$ changes to $v=1$;

$y=1-x$ changes to $u=1$;

$y=0$ gives $v=0$

but what about the boundary $x=1$, where does it go ?.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1270924/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2419007/321264

Answer (score 0):

Consider the transformation $\Phi(u,v)=(x,y)$ given by $x=u(1-v)$ and $y=uv$. Then the Jacobian is $$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=u.$$ 
Moreover $\Phi$ is a bijection, with inverse $u = x+y$, $v = y/(x+y)$, between the open square
$$Q=\{(u,v): u\in (0,1),v\in (0,1)\}$$
and the open triangle
$$T=\{(x,y): x\in (0,1), 0< y< 1-x\}.$$
Therefore
$$\iint_T e^{\frac{y}{x+y}} \ dy\  dx=\iint_Q e^{v}u \ du\  dv=\frac{e-1}{2}.$$

P.S. Given $v\in [0,1)$, $(x,y)=(u-uv,uv)$ for $u\in (0,1]$ is the parametric equation of a segment along the line $y=\frac{v}{1-v}\cdot x$.

Comment: Thanks but I asked about the image of boundary $x=1$ under the given transformation. Can you please explain how do you get $u=0$?

Comment: See my P.S. The $xy$ triangle is obtained as union of segments along the line $y=\frac{v}{1-v}\cdot x$ with $v\in [0,1)$. When $v\to 1^-$ we obtain the part of the boundary along the $y$-axis.