# Solving a double integral by changing variables

Tags: definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I got a double integral exercise which is shown as below:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\exp\left(\frac y{x + y}\right)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

I have a hint that I should put $u = x + y$ and $v = y$ to solve this question but I still find it hard to solve.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images cannot be searched and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for your link. I am quite confused for math formatting here so I used image. I will try to use math form in a later use.

Comment: In $\int_0^1\int_0^{1\cdot x}$, did you mean $1-x$ ? what did you mean $1.x$?

Comment: @masoud yes thanks, maybe I got the wrong command to write the minus sign. I have edited it

Comment: Wondering about so many upvotes here. Duplicates: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2452982/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2419007/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1270924/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\exp\left(\frac y{x + y}\right)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

$$=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-y}\exp\left(\frac y{x + y}\right)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

so $|J|=1$ sine $v=y$ and $u=x+y$

$0<y<1$ and $x<1-y$

$0<y<1$ and $x+y<1$

$0<v<1$ and $v<u<1$  ( since $y\leq x+y$ )

\begin{eqnarray}
J=\left|
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{d }{du}x &  \frac{d}{dv}x \\
\frac{d}{du}y & \frac{d}{dv} y \\
\end{array}
\right|
=\left|
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1  \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right|
\end{eqnarray}

$$=\int_0^1\int_v^{1}\exp\left(\frac v{u}\right)\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv$$

$$=\int_0^1\int_0^{u}\exp\left(\frac v{u}\right)\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du$$

Comment: There are 2 problems in your answer; 1. How do you find that u and v has the domain [0, 1]x[0,1]; 2. if I calculate your answer, I do not get the proper result as expected

Comment: How do you know $y \leq x +y$?

Comment: since both x and y are greater than $0$.  just need to $x>0$